# QDialog show() - before displaying, the window area is painted white

Tags: qt, qdialog

```
auto*w=new Dialog1();
w->show();
```

QDialog show() - before displaying, the window area is painted white. You may not notice this on fast computers. How to avoid this ?

If I use

```
auto*w=new Dialog1();
w->setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint); 
w->show();
```

then there is no white paint, but there is no window header

Windows 10. Desktop Qt 5.15.0 MinGW 64-bit

Link to project https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vpuon7lIByZzgjJ0nBg8qU1e5SZAX46Z/view

Video - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-gs5UrD62f_JIUFYu4zZftSaxCAbV9zr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you share some screenshots and your code? That would help make the problem clearer.

Comment: If you think this is due to the computer's performance, you can test it by having just `main()` calling a single `QDialog`. If the problem is still there, then it should not be a Qt problem.

Comment: If you think it is a Qt problem, then consider posting the whole code, including how `Dialog1` is constructed and how its layout. Maybe we can have more clues there.

Comment: Which platform are you on?

Comment: Windows 10. Desktop Qt 5.15.0 MinGW 64-bit. Link to project 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vpuon7lIByZzgjJ0nBg8qU1e5SZAX46Z/view?usp=sharing
You can slow down the speed of your computer by 4 times - Power supply\Changing system parameters\Change additional power settings\Energy saving

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved this problem**

```
class Dialog1 : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
 
public:
    explicit Dialog1(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~Dialog1();
 
private:
    Ui::Dialog1 *ui;
protected:
    bool event(QEvent*e);
};

Dialog1::Dialog1(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),ui(new Ui::Dialog1)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
 
    setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);
    setWindowOpacity(0);
}
 
bool Dialog1::event(QEvent*e)
{
    if(e->type()==QEvent::WindowActivate)
    {
        QTimer::singleShot(0,NULL,[this](){this->setWindowOpacity(1);});
        return true;
    }
    if(e->type()==QEvent::Hide)
    {
        setWindowOpacity(0);
        return true;
    }
    return QDialog::event(e);
}
```

This is not a Qt problem, this is a Windows problem. I looked at my WPF and Windows Forms projects and saw that they have this problem. You can also see it by running Windows Explorer or Windows Task Manager. Another question is whether this is considered a problem. I think so, Yes. This flickering hits my eyes

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and found that MainWindow is painted white on the start, but both dialogs are OK.

I'll show how to address the MainWindow issue, and you can use it with any widget.

The problem is, at the very first painting, QPainter takes some time to be initialized. So the solution is to perform first paint before the window is shown.

Code:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow w;
    w.grab(); // draw to an offscreen buffer
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: w.grab(); doesn't solve the problem. The white paint remained

Comment: Video - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-gs5UrD62f_JIUFYu4zZftSaxCAbV9zr/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I slowed down my computer as you suggested and tried the same Qt version. I can confirm that `grab()` improves the situation, but doesn't solve it completely.